# Default Template infinite loop of Title

Tags: loop, themes, pages

Pages which have no specific template assigned output an infinite amount of h2 page titles, which looks like this:
[image]

This is what my Themes index.php looks like:

```
get_header(); ?>
    Hallo
get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks for helping me out. I am new to Wordpress.

Comment: Your index.php can't look like what you have pasted, otherwise you will not get the output you showed

Comment: @PieterGoosen Um it does look like that. The template is "default" and the index.php is located here: "wp-content/theme/mytheme/"

Comment: What theme are you using

Comment: My own theme. I can even have an empty index.php and it gets the same output ._.

Comment: Set your debug to true in wp_config.php and check for errors. Also try switching to a default theme. I might be way off here, but it sounds like a hack

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't get an error. But the Wordpress bar on top of the page is not showing as well. This is the url: http://www.norizon-factory.com/test/obermayr/risk-engineering/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14806/discussion-between-christoph-buhler-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: I had a page.php file on the server with some weird codings going on, but not locally. Now, it works.

Comment: That weird coding might be a hack. Just be careful for that. Glad you got things sorted though